# In TypeScript, how to specify method chaining result type if methods can alter that type?

Tags: typescript, generics, method-chaining

Suppose I want to achieve the following behavior:

```
const x = new ChainableClass<any>();
x.get(); // -> any[] (default)
x.all().get(); // -> any[]
x.single().get(); // -> any
x.all().single().all().get(); // -> any
```

Methods alter the `value` (it can be any type) and return `this` to continue the chain.
`get` returns either **single** `value` or **array** of `values`.

Below is how I tried to implement such class:

```
export class ChainableClass<TEntity, TResult = TEntity[]> {
  private value: any; // arbitrary value
  
  all(): ChainableClass<TEntity, TResult> {
    // TODO implementation
    return this;
  }

  // notice I change second type to TEntity (it's TEntity[] by default)
  single(): ChainableClass<TEntity, TEntity> { 
    // TODO implementation
    return this; // TS2322 error here
  }

  anotherAll(): ChainableClass<TEntity, TResult> {
    // TODO implementation
    return this;
  }

  get(): TResult {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

However, TypeScript emits error if I alter `TResult` like in `single` method.

```
src/ChainableClass.ts:9:5 - error TS2322: Type 'this' is not assignable to type 'ChainableClass<TEntity, TEntity>'.
  Type 'ChainableClass<TEntity, TResult>' is not assignable to type 'ChainableClass<TEntity, TEntity>'.
    Type 'TResult' is not assignable to type 'TEntity'.
      'TEntity' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'TResult'.

9     return this;
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can suppress it by casting `this` to `any` but I feel like I miss something important here.
Is my implementation incorrect fundamentally?
What is the possible way to implement described class type-safe?

Edit: error occurs only if I have `get` method in class.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz doesn't help. Also: this error occurs only if I have `get` method.

Comment: The compiler won't understand mutating the type of `this`, so you'll have to use a type assertion (what you're calling "casting") to convince the compiler that's okay, and you need to be careful that you're really returning a value of the right type, since the compiler can't help you.  If you really want to be type safe, don't return `this`; create a brand new instance of the right type and return that without modifying the original instance.

Comment: I'd be happy to write up an answer but this example isn't [mcve] enough, I think.  Can you make some reasonable dependence on `TEntity` and `TResult` in the example?  Shouldn't `value` be of type `TResult`?  Where does `TEntity` show up? Without a functioning example it's hard to give an answer that will work.  Maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/PmL2aw)?

Comment: I'm afraid I already tried my best to provide minimal example. The reason is that in my actual code it's not the `value` that I return using `get`, it's a value from 3rd party lib and it could be either `any` or `any[]`. This class is a wrapper actually, it forwards method calls to 3rd party code. Making `ChainableClass` immutable is surely an option but I don't think it's necessary in my case because I can guarantee type correctness in runtime (single value vs array).

Comment: Seems like if return value is mutating during the chain, then my only option is either to construct a new instance or perform unsafe operation (`<any>this`), at least I couldn't find any better way to do that.

Comment: An [mcve] doesn't have use your actual code, it just has to demonstrate your issue and only your issue. The use of `any` muddles what sort of guarantee you're looking for; everything is assignable to/from `any`, including `any[]`. Also the example code reuses `x` multiple times, which is a problem if `x.single()` mutates `x`. Fluent/chainable methods with mutation usually precludes reusing intermediate results.  Did you see the [code I linked](https://tsplay.dev/PmL2aw) and does it suffice?

Comment: Or maybe even [this](https://tsplay.dev/vwj1kW)?